# Copy multiple text files with same name from multiple folders to new folders within a folder structure

Tags: python

I have a master folder that contains 93 folders with unique names that have in each 4 subfolders and a README.txt file. Each subfolder has various other files. I want to replicate that folder structure to create a new master folder with a different naming convention, empty subfolders, and a copy of the text file from the previous master folder. I have been able to create the new directory and all the subfolders but am stuck at the part where I transfer over the text files. There are 93 text files that have the same naming convention but are in 93 different folders. I am able to transfer over the text file but unfortunately, it keeps copying over a text file from each folder and replacing it over the previous. **What I want it to do is take each text file from each unique folder and place it into the same folder just in the newly created master folder structure.**

```
import os, glob, shutil

folder_temp = r'Z:\RezaH\Test\master'

prov_name = os.listdir(folder_temp)

new_dir = r'Z:\RezaH\Test\holding'

for folders in prov_name:

    folder = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(new_dir, folders))

    isp_prov = os.mkdir(folder)

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_temp):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('README.txt'):
                txt = os.path.join(root, file)

                for txt_file in glob.glob(txt):
                    shutil.copy2(txt, isp_prov)

for subfolder in ['correspondence', 'fromProv', 'processed', 'working']:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(folder, subfolder))
```

I am new to python and have been trying to find hints online but to no avail. So alas, here is my last-ditch effort to finding a solution. I appreciate the time and thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you possibly illustrate (with a text block) a small example of the old and new folder/file structure so your intentions are more understandable?

Comment: Hi Matt! So the master folder would look something like Z:\Master\2019April_data. The subfolders would be names of certain companies. That folder would look something like Z:\Master\2019April_data\Comcast. lastly, the subfolders and text files would be located within the company folder to look something like this Z:\Master\2019April_data\Comcast\README.txt. The new file structure I want to move the text file to is Z:\Master\2020April_data\Comcast. How do I write code that moves that text file from the 2019 folder to the same company folder in the 2020 path?

Comment: Im a little lost from your original post, but from your edit, seems like you can get the original file `txt = os.path.join(root, file)`, replace the April part `txt2 = txt.replace('2019', '2020')` and copy `shutil.copy2(txt, txt2)`

Comment: Matt! That worked! Thanks so much! I'm glad I could make more sense the 2nd time around. I appreciate it! Have a great week!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. You have a great week as well